# Outputting html image and link tags to text files and displaying to user

Tags: java

I would like to start by saying that I am new to StackOverflow, so please forgive me if I make any newbie mistakes.

I have been assigned to write a java swing program that searches a URL (specified by user), then pull the HTML code, and display all the image tags and link tags found in the HTML code. As of right now, I have a GUI that consists of one JTextField for the user to specify the URL, two JTextArea's to output link tags and image tags, and a search button. Once the user has searched a URL, the HTML code is read in and if the line contains an image tag or link tag it is written to the corresponding text file. However, I would like to narrow it down to where only the image tags and only the link tags are written to the text files, rather than writing the entire line on which they were found. How could I go about doing this?

Any help would be appreciated. Here is what I have so far.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WebSearch extends JFrame
{
  // create a JLabel to prompt user, two JTextArea's to output results,
  // a JTextField to take user input, and a JButton to run the application.
  private JTextField inputBox;
  private JLabel userPrompt;
  private JTextArea imageResults;
  private JTextArea linkResults;
  private JButton startButton;

  // create a constructor to add GUI components
  public WebSearch()
  {
    // set title bar
    super( "Links and Images from URL" );
    inputBox = new JTextField( 33 );
    startButton = new JButton( "Search" );
    // add ActionListener to detect when action is performed
    startButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    { 
      // override actionPerformed method 
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
      {
        String input = inputBox.getText();
        try
        {
          URL url = new URL( input );
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( url.openStream() ));
          String inputLine;
          PrintWriter imageWriter = new PrintWriter( "images.txt", "UTF-8" );
          PrintWriter linkWriter = new PrintWriter( "links.txt", "UTF-8" );
          FileReader imageReader = new FileReader( "images.txt" );
          FileReader linkReader = new FileReader( "links.txt" );
          while(( inputLine = in.readLine() ) != null )
          {
            if( inputLine.contains( "<a href=" ))
            {
              linkWriter.println( inputLine );
            }
            if( inputLine.contains( "<img src=" ))
            {
              imageWriter.println( inputLine );
            }
         }
          imageWriter.close();
          linkWriter.close();
          imageResults.read( imageReader, "images.txt" );
          linkResults.read( linkReader, "links.txt" );
          in.close();
        }
         catch( Exception exception )
        {
        }
      } // end actionPerformed method
    } // end innerclass
    ); // end ActionListener
    userPrompt = new JLabel( "Enter a URL:" );
    inputBox.setText( "http://www." );
    linkResults = new JTextArea( 8, 33 );
    linkResults.setEditable( false );
    imageResults = new JTextArea( 8, 33 );
    imageResults.setEditable( false ); 
    linkResults.setText( "Image tags listed here" );
    imageResults.setText( "Link tags listed here" );
    // create scroll panes for JTextArea's
    JScrollPane imageScrollPane = new JScrollPane( imageResults );
    JScrollPane linkScrollPane = new JScrollPane( linkResults );
    // add GUI components to container
    Container container = getContentPane();
    container.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
    container.add( userPrompt );
    container.add( inputBox );
    container.add( startButton );
    container.add( imageScrollPane );
    container.add( linkScrollPane );
    setSize( 400, 400 );
    setVisible( true );
    setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
  } // end constructor

  // create main method and object of class WebSearch
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    WebSearch application = new WebSearch();
  } // end main method
} // end class
```

Comment: You should use a html parsing library.  You are going line by line, but what if there's a line wrap?  Check out the tagsoup library, you'll then be able to reference the src variable of an img tag and the href of an a tag.

Comment: Since you've narrowed down your problem, try to trim your posted code to only include the things relevant to that portion.  In your case, your question simplifies to retrieving an attribute of an HTML string.

Comment: A HTML parser library might be very helpful to do this. For example: JSoup: http://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off relying on an HTML parse library like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). Be that as it may - presuming the HTML is well formed you will need to parse what is inside the quotes for each element. A simple way to do this is to parse everything between the quotes within the element:

```
    String valueToFind = "<img src=\"";
    int index = inputLine.indexOf(valueToFind );
    if ( index != -1 ){
        StringBuilder link = new StringBuilder();
        index += valueToFind.length();
        while ( index < inputLine.length() && inputLine.charAt(index) != '"'){
            link.append(inputLine.charAt(index));
            index++;
        }
        System.out.println(link);
    }
```

Note this does *NOT* account for multiple tags on a single line (easily modified to do so however), and it does *NOT* account for HTML that is not well formed (multiple spaces after img or the element line wrapped - think regular expression, or why reinvent the wheel and just use an HTML parser).